# recursion function to find fibonnaci series

Tags: python, recursion

I wanted to making this code work to find out the fibonacci series with recursion but i don't understand why my code fails to do that

```
class fib: #fibonacci series 
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, a , b,count):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.count=count;

    def fibb(self, a , b,count):
        if(self.count > count):
            return;
        else:
            if(self.count == 0):
                print a
                print b
                self.count = self.count + 1
                print " counting : ", self.count
                self.c = self.a + self.b
                self.a = self.b
                self.b = self.c
                #print self.a , ", ",self.b
                return fibb(self.a,self.b,count)
            else:
                print b
                self.count = self.count + 1
                print " counting : ", self.count
                self.c = self.a + self.b
                self.a = self.b
                self.b = self.c
                #print self.a , ", ",self.b
                return fibb(self.a,self.b,count)
fib1 = fib(1,2,0) # creating object
fib1.fibb(1,1,10)  # calling function
```

```
My Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jdoodle.py", line 36, in 
fib1.fibb(1,1,10)  # calling function
File "jdoodle.py", line 24, in fibb
return fibb(self.a,self.b,count)
NameError: global name 'fibb' is not defined
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

Comment: I think you should be able to write recursive Fibonacci in about 10 lines of code.  Why take such a complex approach?

Comment: If you want to execute the class method, you must write ``return self.fibb(self.a,self.b,count)``. Notice the ``self.`` before the method name, otherwise Python is looking for a function ``fibb`` in the global scope.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Cool.  But of course recursion isn't the best way to do this anyway :-)

Comment: Why are you using a class here? Why not just a plain function? There really is no need for all this state. Anyway, your error stems from using `fibb` instead of `self.fibb`

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.fibb` when referencing the function. Python doesn't explicitly know to call the fibb function within the class